# How to change simple form post into an AJAX calls

Tags: ajax, forms, post, webforms

I have a really simple webform;

```
<form name="logmeinsupport" action="https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/Customer/Code.aspx" method="post">
<span>Enter your 6-digit PIN code: </span><input type="text" name="Code" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Connect to technician" />
</form>
```

On the logmeinrescue side, there will post the error code back into URL:

Like:  http://tomtom-uk--tst2.tomtom.com/app/utils/support_login?LogMeInRescueResponse=PINCODE_INVALID

However, our server setup interprets it as a page in web server, therefore, i got 404 error:

404 Page Not Found

The page 'utils/support_login?LogMeInRescueResponse=PINCODE_INVALID.php' was not found.

It is not so easy for our infrastructure team to change it. I am wondering whether I can use Ajax call backs post function to get response. And i think the difficult is about cross server ajax call.

Any examples? Thanks

Cheers,
Qing

Comment: `utils/support_login?LogMeInRescueResponse=PINCODE_INVALID.php` is unlikely to be found because you have the `.php` extension after the parameters. I think you probably meant `utils/support_login.php?LogMeInRescueResponse=PINCODE_INVALID`

Answer (score 0):

The server looks for the file 'utils/support_login?LogMeInRescueResponse=PINCODE_INVALID.php'.

I think you should change your request to:

```
utils/support_login.php?LogMeInRescueResponse=PINCODE_INVALID
```

In this way the server will look for support_login.php and if there is indeed a file with this name on your server you will not have this error again.

Comment: I do not get that. I can not change my request to utils/support_login.php?LogMeInRescueResponse=PINCODE_INVALID . Because i want to get a response from https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/Customer/Code.aspx

Comment: Check your secure.logmeinrescue.com/Customer/Code.aspx - in there you can have a request to support_login.php